# Passing object through ObjectDataSource Asp.net Error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, repository, objectdatasource

I'm working on a school project and I'm running into an error that has stumped me. I'm using entity framework, repository pattern, and object data source. The error I'm getting happens when I'm trying to insert a productvariant using the product ID foreign key(which is a urlparameter).

**Error**

ObjectDataSource 'ProductVariantObjectDataSource' could not find a non-generic method 'InsertProductVariantByProductId' that takes parameters of type 'FV_ProductVariant'.

**Link to image**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJeR1.png

**Stack Trace:**

[InvalidOperationException: ObjectDataSource 'ProductVariantObjectDataSource' could not find a non-generic method 'InsertProductVariantByProductId' that takes parameters of type 'FV_ProductVariant'.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.GetResolvedMethodData(Type type, String methodName, Type dataObjectType, Object oldDataObject, Object newDataObject, DataSourceOperation operation) +1355789
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteInsert(IDictionary values) +339
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Insert(IDictionary values, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +89
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleInsert(String commandArg, Boolean causesValidation) +379
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +574
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +112
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +169
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

**The object datasource within the aspx page**

```
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ProductVariantObjectDataSource" runat="server" 
    DataObjectTypeName="FV_ProductVariant" InsertMethod="InsertProductVariantByProductId" 
    SelectMethod="GetProductVariantByProductId" TypeName="ProductBL">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="productVariant" Type="Object" />
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="productId" QueryStringField="ProductId" 
            Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="productId" QueryStringField="ProductId" 
            Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**ProductBL where the ObjectDataSource is inserting with**

```
    public void InsertProductVariantByProductId(FV_ProductVariant productVariant, int productId)
{
    try
    {
        productRepository.InsertProductVariantByProductId(productVariant, productId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**The IRepository**

```
    void InsertProductVariantByProductId(FV_ProductVariant productVariant, int ProductId);
```

**The actual Repository**

```
    public void InsertProductVariantByProductId(FV_ProductVariant productVariant, int productId)
{
    try
    {
        productVariant.ProductVariantId = GenerateProductVariantID();
        productVariant.ProductId = productId;
        context.FV_ProductVariant.AddObject(productVariant);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Creating an ObjectDataSource Control Source Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227436.aspx)

> If the source object for an `ObjectDataSource` control exposes public static methods (Shared in Visual Basic) that can be called to retrieve and modify data, an `ObjectDataSource` control will call those methods directly. If an `ObjectDataSource` control must create an instance of the source object in order to make method calls, the object must include a public constructor that takes no parameters. The `ObjectDataSource` control will call this constructor when it creates a new instance of the source object.
>
> If the source object does not contain
>   a public constructor without
>   parameters, you can create an instance
>   of the source object that will be used
>   by the `ObjectDataSource` control in the
>   `ObjectCreating` event...

Also, try making your method `static`.

```
public static void InsertProductVariantByProductId(FV_ProductVariant productVariant, int productId)
{
    try
    {
        productRepository.InsertProductVariantByProductId(productVariant, productId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```